# If condition query for mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an collection with documents that can be public or private. I am looking to have a single query that can get a document by an _id and check if it's private. If it is private it needs to check if the user requesting the document is a participant in the object.

Here is the object:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5769ae620e80ea1c7f8a997f"),
    "owner" : ObjectId("5740edae95a1b4c043d033df"),
    "private" : false,
    "participants" : [
        {
            "uid" : ObjectId("5740edae95a1b4c043d033df"),
            "notify" : true
        }
    ],
    "messages" : [ ]
}
```

This is the 2 step query I wrote and wondering if I can simplify it

```
function getRoom(roomId, user){

    db.rooms.findOne({ _id: pmongo.ObjectId(roomId) })
        .then(room => {
          if(room.private){
            return db.rooms.findOne({
              _id: pmongo.ObjectId(roomId),
              participants: {$eleMatch: {uid: String(user._id)}}
            })
          } else {
            return room
          }
        })

    }
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB has [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator which can be used in this case:

```
db.rooms.findOne({ $or: [
  {
    _id: pmongo.ObjectId(roomId),
    private: { $ne: true }
  }, {
    _id: pmongo.ObjectId(roomId),
    participants: {$eleMatch: {uid: String(user._id)}}
  }
]})
```

Comment: Awesome! Let me give that a shot!

Comment: Yes, it should give a little more speed but if property `private` will be empty it will fails so there should be the default value in a Room model.